# How to Show Current Fiscal Year's Revenue from Accounts Created From Google Ads Prior to This Year?

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type, custom-reports

I'm trying to create a report that allows me to see closed won opportunities from the current fiscal year, but only from accounts created prior to this year and created from a Google Ads campaign (this is a linked field passed along from Pardot).

We have a custom report type of "Accounts & Contacts with Opportunities & Quotes" that gives me access to all the fields I need to filter by, but my report only returns the total closed/won for the entire account and won't return just the current year's revenue.

Is this caused by the report type being based on the account object with opportunities being included? Should it be opportunities with the account object being included?

It doesn't appear that an accounts report or an opportunities report gives me access to all the fields I need.

I don't have admin access to create new report types. I'm sure I can have the admin do it on Monday if that is the route I need to take.

How do I create this report?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is [Cross Filters](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.reports_cross_filters.htm&type=5) to apply filtering on the results of the related object in the report (ex. Opportunity)

> Use a cross filter to fine-tune your results by including or excluding records from related objects and their fields, without having to write formulas or code. You can apply cross filters by themselves, or in combination with field filters.

[image]

That should allow you to do that filter by Accounts with Opportunities created/closed in certain time periods.

[image]